# parentNode не видит родителей

Tags: javascript, dom

Моя задача реализовать логику которая связана с поиском родительского элемента по классу. Пробовал реализовать через closest. Понял что код не работает. Заменил closest на getParents и увидел, что у элемента li условно не хватает родителей )). Из этого вытекают дальнейшие рассуждения.

Я добавляю на страницу HTML список элементов ul при помощи js. И когда пытаюсь получить родительские элементы у li то последний родитель который будет найден это ul, хотя их (родителей) на много больше.

Есть блок HTML

```
<div class="select-list select-list__city-choice tariffs-popup">
    <div class=" select-list__list-wrapper scrollbar">
     (сюда js вставляет список элементов ul)
    </div>   
</div>
```

Код который создаёт и добавляет список. В порядке вызова

```
handlerCkickPopupActionBtn(currentTarget) {
    //сработает при клике по кнопке открытия всплывающего окна с данными для выбора
    const parentElement = currentTarget.parentElement;
    const windowElement = parentElement.nextElementSibling;

    let optionList = windowElement.querySelector(".select-list__list");
    // если ранее был создан лист опций то удаляем его
    if (optionList) {
      optionList.remove();
    }

    **optionList = this.createSelectList(windowElement)**;
    if (
      currentTarget.classList.contains("many-input-select__city-choice_open")
    ) {
      windowElement
        .querySelector(".select-list__list-wrapper")
        .appendChild(optionList);
    } else {
      windowElement.appendChild(optionList);
    }

    if (!windowElement.classList.contains("visible")) {
      windowElement.classList.add("visible");
    }

    // если это кнопка открытия окна с городами, то спрячем её и покажем кнопку закрытия окна
    if (
      currentTarget.classList.contains("many-input-select__city-choice_open")
    ) {
      this.togleOpenCitiesSelectList();
    }
  }
```

```
**createSelectList(parentElement)** {
    // cоздаёт список опций
    let list;
    if (
      Array.from(parentElement.classList).some((_class) =>
        _class.includes("mediametry")
      )
    ) {
      list = this.createMediametryList();
    }
    if (
      Array.from(parentElement.classList).some((_class) =>
        _class.includes("city-choice")
      )
    ) {
      **list = this.createCityChoiceList();**
    }
    return list;
  }
```

```
**createCityChoiceList(citiesProp)** {
    // создаём список с городами
    const list = document.createElement("ul");
    list.classList.add(
      "select-list__list",
      "many-input-select__city-choice__list"
    );
    const citis = citiesProp || Object.keys(this.modCities);

    for (let i = 0; i < citis.length; i++) {
      const item = document.createElement("li");
      item.classList.add(
        "select-list__item",
        "many-input-select__city-choice__item"
      );
      item.append(document.createElement("p"));
      if (this.modCities[citis[i]].state === "active") {
        item.classList.add(
          "selected-city-element",
          "selected-city-element--active"
        );
        this.addCloseButton(item);
      } else {
        item.classList.remove(
          "selected-city-element",
          "selected-city-element--active"
        );
      }

      item.querySelector("p").innerText = citis[i];
      list.appendChild(item);
    }
    return list;
  }
```

При попытке получить родителей элемента списка Li при помощи кода

```
document.addEventListener("click", (e) => this.handlerClickOnDocument(e));

handlerClickOnDocument({ target }) {
   console.log(this.getParents(target));
}

getParents(elem) {
    var parents = [];
    while (
      elem.parentNode &&
      elem.parentElement.nodeName.toLowerCase() != "body"
    ) {
      elem = elem.parentNode;
      parents.push(elem);
    }
    return parents;
  }
```

я получаю родителей до элемента ul включительно. Более дальних родителей я не получаю. Вод вывод из консоли:
[image: вывод из консоли родителей]

При этом если вызвать функцию вывода родителей из консоли (как на скрине ниже отображаются все родители)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ест подозрение что так происходит по тому что элементы добавлены js. Но так ли то. И как исправить ситуацию

Comment: попробуйте заменить elem = elem.parentNode на elem = elem.parentElement; И вообще не использовать parentNode, возможно вопрос в узлах-элементах

Comment: @Arbery пробовал. Дело не в этом. closest тоже не работает.

Comment: создайте рабочую болванку - 1й кусок кода со всей структурой html которая на последнем скрине видна (хоть из html скопируйте) и последний с кодом для получения всех родителей. Сейчас даже на практике не проверить - что там в li намешано и как оно реагирует. И для чего этот обработчик с getParents должен работать? Для li? Сейчас он на всем документе срабатывает и даже не проверяет на чем клик сделан.

Comment: @Arbery я добавил пояснения в верхнюю часть вопроса. Может это прояснит что к чему ). getParents просто показывает что там где должны быть родители их нет

Answer (score 0):

> Ест подозрение что так происходит по тому что элементы добавлены js. Но так ли то. И как исправить ситуацию

Скрипт тут точно не виноват... Смотри, все работает (запускал в Опере).

```js
test.addEventListener('click', _ => {
  const o = document.querySelector('li')
  const prnt = o => {
    o = o?.parentNode
    if (!o?.tagName) return
    console.log(o.tagName, o.className)
    prnt(o)
  }
  prnt(o)
})
add.addEventListener('click', _ => {
  const html = `
    <ul>
      <li>Элемент 1</li>
      <li>Элемент 2</li>
      <li>Элемент 3</li>
    </ul>
  `
  document.querySelector('.select-list__list-wrapper').innerHTML = html
})
```

```html
<button id='test'>Тест родителей li</button>
<button id='add'>Добавить контент</button>

<div class="select-list select-list__city-choice tariffs-popup">
    <div class="select-list__list-wrapper scrollbar"></div>   
</div>
```